# HDD LEDs stopped working after exchanged raid controller in HP DL380 G5

Tags: hard-drive, hp, hp-proliant, lsi, hba

I recently went ahead and exchanged the p400 RAID controller in my HP DL380 G5 server with an LSI HBA card (SAS 9207-8i). I did this to get better disk compatibility, and I didn't need RAID functionality. I popped a few Samsung SSDs in the machine and they where perfectly recognised.

The only issue I am having is that the HDD LEDs aren't working anymore. They quickly flash when I power on the server, but afterwards they do not blink on disk activity. Before I started using the HBA card, it was blinking on disk activity. Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not. You've added a foreign component to the HP system. It can't be expected to work the same way as native parts.

My experience with LSI controllers running the internal disks of a ProLiant server is that the disk LED activity is random or may not correlate to what's actually happening. But in the end, it really doesn't matter.

It's worth noting that your (SATA) SSDs are probably running at a lower link speed than you expect. The G5 backplane (and hardware) is very old, so yeah...

Comment: Ok. I am very new to managing HP and linux. Do you know if I can toggle the indicator led for a particular disk. I hoped that i would be able to use something like sgpio, but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Nope, you've chosen to run your server WAAAY outside of the expected configuration, you have to deal with the consequences.